# Message not dispatched async despite configuring the handler route to be async in Symfony Messenger

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-messenger

I'm working with Symfony 4.4 and Symfony Messenger

Messenger configuration includes a transport and routing:

```yaml
messenger:
    failure_transport: failed

    transports:
        async_medium:
            dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
            retry_strategy:
                max_retries: 3
                delay: 1000
        failed:
            ...

    routing:
        'Name\Space\MessageHandler\SnowplowNotificationHandler': async_medium
```

Though the handler looks like configured correctly (when I run console debug:messenger it shows up correctly assigned to transport)

```
Messenger

messenger.bus.default

 The following messages can be dispatched:
  Name\Space\Message\SnowplowMessage                                                  
     handled by Name\Space\MessageHandler\SnowplowEmailNotificationHandler
```

The message class `SnowplowMessage` is not queued, but sent instantly to the `_invoke()` method of the handler.

I'm using AMQP (RabbitMQ as transport) and it's configured properly as no error is shown and the command console messenger:setup-transport creates the queue properly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason this seems to be an error that happens with some frequency, so I rather post an answer instead of a comment.

You are supposed to add **message** classes to the routing configuration, **not handler classes**.

Your configuration should be, if you want that message to be manages asynchronously:

```yaml
routing:
        Name\Space\Message\SnowplowMessage: async_medium
```

What you are routing are **message**. Since the above configuration was missing, the default routing was processing the message syncrhonously.

Comment: thank you for the help with this. I was successfully unblocked :)

Comment: I had similar a situation which confused configure namespace of message with handler class